# moveit_benchmark_gui compile error

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile moveit from the source. But when I try to compile `moveit_benchmark_gui`, I am getting a linker error as below.

```
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/main_window.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/lonewolf/workspace/ros/secondary_packages/devel_isolated/moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui/lib/moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui/moveit_benchmark_gui
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/main_window.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::MainWindow::updateGoalPoseMarkers(float, float)':
main_window.cpp:(.text+0x1167): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::update(float)'
main_window.cpp:(.text+0x11ab): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::update(float)'
main_window.cpp:(.text+0x11ca): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::update(float)'
main_window.cpp:(.text+0x11e9): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::update(float)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/frame_marker.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::FrameMarker::showDescription(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x5f6): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::processMessage(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x645): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setPose(Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::Quaternion, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x66a): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowDescription(bool)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/frame_marker.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::FrameMarker::setColor(float, float, float, float)':
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x7cc): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::processMessage(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x81b): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setPose(Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::Quaternion, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/frame_marker.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::FrameMarker::setPose(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0>&)':
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x1535): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setPose(Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::Quaternion, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/frame_marker.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::FrameMarker::buildFrom(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, geometry_msgs::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const&, double, std_msgs::ColorRGBA_<std::allocator<void> > const&)':
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x1f11): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::InteractiveMarker(Ogre::SceneNode*, rviz::DisplayContext*)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x1f87): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::processMessage(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x1f98): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowVisualAids(bool)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x1fa6): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowAxes(bool)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x1fb4): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowDescription(bool)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/frame_marker.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::GripperMarker::buildFrom(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, geometry_msgs::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const&, double, std_msgs::ColorRGBA_<std::allocator<void> > const&)':
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x382e): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::InteractiveMarker(Ogre::SceneNode*, rviz::DisplayContext*)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x38a2): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::processMessage(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x38b0): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowAxes(bool)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x38c1): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowVisualAids(bool)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x38cf): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowDescription(bool)'
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x39b9): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setPose(Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::Quaternion, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/frame_marker.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::FrameMarker::hideDescription()':
frame_marker.cpp:(.text+0x27a): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setShowDescription(bool)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/frame_marker.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::FrameMarker::updateMarker()':
frame_marker.cpp:(.text._ZN14benchmark_tool11FrameMarker12updateMarkerEv[_ZN14benchmark_tool11FrameMarker12updateMarkerEv]+0xc): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::processMessage(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/trajectory.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::Trajectory::trajectoryMarkerFeedback(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedback_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
trajectory.cpp:(.text+0x1765): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setPose(Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::Quaternion, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/trajectory.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::Trajectory::rebuildWayPointMarkers()':
trajectory.cpp:(.text+0x2eb8): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setPose(Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::Quaternion, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/src/tab_states_and_goals.cpp.o: In function `benchmark_tool::MainWindow::goalPoseFeedback(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedback_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
tab_states_and_goals.cpp:(.text+0xe467): undefined reference to `rviz::InteractiveMarker::setPose(Ogre::Vector3, Ogre::Quaternion, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/build.make:538: recipe for target '/home/lonewolf/workspace/ros/secondary_packages/devel_isolated/moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui/lib/moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui/moveit_benchmark_gui' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/lonewolf/workspace/ros/secondary_packages/devel_isolated/moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui/lib/moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui/moveit_benchmark_gui] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:680: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/moveit_benchmark_gui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui': 
  Command '['/home/lonewolf/workspace/ros/secondary_packages/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

But I have both the rviz and InteractiveMarkers packages installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231053/moveit_benchmark_gui-compile-error/) by [lonewolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23977/lonewolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-09**:
@lonewolf: please accept the answer by @130s by ticking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a [related ticket](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/654). As mentioned in the ticket, with the latest commit you should be able to compile.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lonewolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23977/lonewolf/) on 2016-04-08**:
Yup.. I just found that and was able to compile with the latest version of rviz.